# Setting up infiniteScroll in angularjs with default code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, infinite-scroll

here is the link to the full code.
http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_async.html#

I copied the code from infiniteScoll's website and it is still not working. The error I am receiving is "$window is not a function". Could someone direct me to a tutorial or maybe something better? Also it fails to instantiate when I add 'infiniteScroll' to `angular.module('starter', ['infiniteScroll'])`

What am I doing wrong? I tried using my own customized code but that doesn't work. I copy and paste the code from the sample they have there and even that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this script:

http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/

Comment: Another question I have is would this be good on a phonegap app on ios android? since it is using jquery.

Comment: I don't know, but for complete support it's convenient to use jquery mobile

Answer (score 0):

Infinite scroll uses Jquery as dependency. You will need to include Jquery and it will work.

Comment: single-line solution/suggestion should be posted in comments.